# How many authentic Gitas are there?

Tags: scripture, gita

How many authentic 'Gitas' are there? Is there any scriptural reference listing them? I have heard of Bhagavad Gita, Ishvara Gita, Ashtavakra Gita. I would like to know the total Gitas present and if they are published by any Mathams or publishers?

Comment: The question got closed with my close vote alone .. Do you have anything to say about the closure?

Comment: @Rickross https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/171/scripture?userid=4732

Comment: This is a duplicate question that has already been answered.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto yes I know why it got closed with my vote alone